# Ubuntu - NTFS Drive Error

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive

Re-formatted a PC of mine from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

I'm having an issue with a secondary HDD that I used to use on the PC, currently my drive configuration is as below.

1. 128GB SSD (OS/System)
2. 2TB HDD (Storage)

Drive 2 is currently NTFS and has a Windows file system on there.

**The Error**
[image]

**My Question**

I'd like to format this drive for use with Ubuntu, how can I acomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, normally booting windows or using chkdsk would resolve this, but now that your using Ubuntu not an option. Ubuntu has something similar to chkdsk (fsck), but it don't support ntfs. Your solution should be as follows

```
 sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
 sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

This will fix it so you can get it to mount and so you can access any files that may be there. You can still use ntfs with Ubuntu, but if you really want to format it, you may want to repartition first

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

Press d to delete, then n to add and just enter through defaults, assuming you have and only want one partition on there. When done, press w to write the changes

Then to format to Linux filesystem ext4

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

**Warning** if you change filesystem to ext4 the drive will no longer be able to be read by Windows, only Linux. So if this is a big drive, and you intend to file share with Windows computers or ever want to plug into a windows computer to access files, I would keep it ntfs

Edit: if you don't care about files and still want to use ntfs, I think you would have to use GParted to reformat as NTFS.

Comment: No problem. Glad could be of help.